# Armature doesn't move mesh

Tags: armature

I'm new to blender and i've been following a tutorial to create an armature for my mesh, everything went good, until I applied the armature to the mesh. Some parts seem to not move at all.

[image]

I don't really know how to fix this, can somebody help?

Comment: Been a while since I animated in Blender now, but you have to assign verticies to each bone. This will determine which parts of your model each bone will manipulate as well as how they will be manipulated.

Comment: All `.blend` files should be hosted on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are in  Weight Paint mode, you have two choices, either remove the mesh from bone or add the mesh to the bone,

Please see the attach files

For adding mesh control to the bone
[image]

For removing the control from the bone

[image]
Red means full control, blue means no control, and in between those color, partial controls.

Answer (score 0):

Try using auto armature with great controls in it.

1. Enable add on in user preferences - Search "rigify" and enable it
2. Add -> armature you will have 2 more option added here
3. Adjust the bones with your mesh
4. Ctrl + p, Assign with automatic weights.

Alternatively 
If you still want to use the manual bones

1. Select your mesh
2. Change the object mode to Weight Paint mode
3. here you can add the area to bone or remove an area from a bone using brush tool

I hope it will help you!

Comment: That didn't really worked, it managed to get 2 more parts moving with the mesh, but most of it is still detached.

Comment: Please take a look of details below